# how to change ContentOffSet of UIScrollView Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I create one `UIScrollView` with programmatically code and I have one button in my view (not exist in `UIScrollView`).

when I click on this button go to next page with modal transition. I create Cancel button in next page that when I click on it back to main page (this page have `UIScrollView`).

I want when click on Cancel button and return to main page call one method that is in main page and in this method change `ContentOfSet` my ScrollView... but not working!!!!

this is my code:

**mainView.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    UIScrollView *scrollbar = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width, height)];
    scrollbar.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    scrollbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    scrollbar.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollbar.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollbar.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollbar.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollbar.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [scrollbar setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollbar.frame.size.width * 4,scrollbar.frame.size.height)];
    scrollbar.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    scrollbar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollbar];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)ChangeMainScrollContentOffset{
    scrollbar.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollbar.frame.size.width * (3), 0);
}
```

this button is in root View :

```
- (IBAction)AddView:(id)sender{
    AddStationController *add =  [[AddStationController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddStationController" bundle:nil];
    [add setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

this button is Cancel button for return in my mainView:

```
- (IBAction)BackView:(id)sender{
    mainView *main = [[mainView alloc]init];
    [main ChangeMainScrollContentOffset];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

please guide me about that!!!
I so confused why not working ContentOffSet!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you didn't add **ChangeMainScrollContentOffset** 
method to your ViewController.h file.

Just add it in ViewController.h file and than call it.

Comment: my friend I adding this method in mainView

Answer (score 0):

You second viewController should have reference to previous view controller.

When you do this:

```
mainView *main = [[mainView alloc]init];
[main ChangeMainScrollContentOffset];
```

You create another instance of mainView which not on screen and change contentOffset on *ANOTHER* scrollView :)

You should add property delegate to your AddStationController

**AddStationController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) mainView* delegate;
```

**mainView**:

```
- (IBAction)AddView:(id)sender{
    AddStationController *add =  [[AddStationController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddStationController" bundle:nil];
    >> add.delegate = self; <<
    [add setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Cancel button action**

```
- (IBAction)BackView:(id)sender{

    >> [self.delegate ChangeMainScrollContentOffset]; <<
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: my friend my ScrollView is in mainView & add button is rootView and cancel button is in AddStationController!!! when write your code I take this error : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: So strange architecture... Anyway, you should have a reference in AddStationController to your MainView instance.

Comment: I don't know how to do this please guide me with code

Comment: What happens when you press add button? Do you have reference to mainView in your rootViewController?

Comment: Read this: http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/16/ios-app-passing-data-between-view-controllers/